# python celery - how to add CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE task at runtime to a worker?

Tags: python, celery, scheduler, celerybeat, djcelery

I have created a celery worker with a single celerybeat schedule task which runs at 5 seconds time interval. How can I add another beat task dynamically to the celery worker without stopping it?

Example

```py
app.conf.update(
   CELERY_TASK_RESULT_EXPIRES=3600,
   CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC',
   CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULE = {
    'long-run-5-secs': {
        'task': 'test_proj.tasks.test',
        'schedule': timedelta(seconds=5),
        'args': (16, )
    }
   }
)
```

With the above configuration, I am able to run the celery worker with beat mode successfully.

Now I need add the below beat schedule dynamically:

```py
'long-run-2-secs': {
    'task': 'test_proj.tasks.test',
    'schedule': timedelta(seconds=2),
    'args': (14, ) },
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been looking for solution for the very same problem. I am affraid you'll have to wait for Celery ver.4.0. Dynamic task scheduling is only currently supported in the **development** version : http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/userguide/periodic-tasks.html#beat-entries

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to store the tasks in the database and add remove tasks dynamically. You can use database backed celery beat scheduler for the same. Refer https://django-celery-beat.readthedocs.io/en/latest/. PeriodicTask database store the periodic tasks. You can manipulate the periodic task by using database commands (Django ORM).

This is how I handled the dynamic tasks (Create and stop tasks dynamically).

```
from django_celery_beat.models import PeriodicTask, IntervalSchedule, CrontabSchedule

chon_schedule = CrontabSchedule.objects.create(minute='40', hour='08', day_of_week='*', day_of_month='*', month_of_year='*') # To create a cron schedule. 
schedule = IntervalSchedule.objects.create(every=10, period=IntervalSchedule.SECONDS) # To create a schedule to run everu 10 min.
PeriodicTask.objects.create(crontab=chon_schedule, name='name_to_identify_task',task='name_of_task') # It creates a entry in the database describing that periodic task (With cron schedule).
task = PeriodicTask.objects.create(interval=schedule, name='run for every 10 min', task='for_each_ten_min', ) # It creates a periodic task with interval schedule
```

> Whenever you update a PeriodicTask a counter in this table is also
>   incremented, which tells the celery beat service to reload the
>   schedule from the database.

So you don't need to restart the or kill the beat.
If you want to stop a task when particular criteria met then

```
periodic_task = PeriodicTask.objects.get(name='run for every 10 min')
periodic_task.enabled = False
periodic_task.save()
```

When enabled is False then the periodic task becomes idle. You can again make it active by making `enable = True`.

If you no longer needs the task then you can simply delete the entry.